# init tinyMce from other file

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I have made  some classes that initialize tinyMce
ex:

```
    var tinyMce_reader = function (rp_documentPath, objectID_arr){
     this.objectID_arr = objectID_arr;
     this.idx = 0;
    this.rp_documentPath = rp_documentPath;
      this.doc_sent_arr = [];
     this.doc_modif_arr = [];
}

    tinyMce_reader.prototype.init = function(){
        tinymce.init({
                menu : {},   
                plugins: "preview,print,fullpage",
                toolbar: "fontsizeselect undo redo |  bold italic underline |  aligncenter alignjustify  | bullist numlist outdent indent | print preview",
                statusbar : false,
                valid_elements : '*[*]',
                selector: "textarea",
                width : 798,
                height : 405,
                content_css : "courriers.css"
            });

    for(var i = 0; i < this.objectID_arr.length; i++) {
           this.doc_sent_arr.push(0);
            this.doc_modif_arr.push(0);
        }
}
```

when I instanciate the object from the file, everithing going well, but if I do it from another file, it doesn't work.

Working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var objectID = ['1371','1377'];
var instance = new tinyMce_Fax_reader('<?= $_SESSION['rp_parameters']->rp_urlPath ?>courrier_MR_prereservation.php', objectID,<?= rp_appSession::rp_GetConseiller()->getConseillerID() ?>);//.?object_id='+objectId[0]);
instance.init();
```

not working:

```
include_once(ROOT_PATH."/includes/components/rp_componentTinyMce.php");
$(document).ready(function(){   
var objectID = ['1371','1377'];
var instance = new tinyMce_Fax_reader('<?= $_SESSION['rp_parameters']->rp_urlPath ?>courrier_MR_prereservation.php', objectID,<?= rp_appSession::rp_GetConseiller()->getConseillerID() ?>);//.?object_id='+objectId[0]);
instance.init();
```

Are you guys have any idea?
thank you

Comment: what is `rp_componentTinyMce.php` look like ??

Comment: I have this include:

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?= $_SESSION['rp_parameters']->rp_urlPath ?>includes/library/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

And then it is only javascript code, where I have my classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry,
I've just forgot to add the the textarea tag with a relevant id in the caller file